# VBA Input on A Dataset

Tags: vba, excel, file, input

Thankyou for the time to click on this question. Ive been having problems with placing this data set on my vba code. I always keep on getting a file 'overflow' then a 'file already opened' error. The data set I am using is a data recordings of power consumption over time. And this set of data is meant to be put into 7 arrays. These are the datasets.

https://data.world/databeats/household-power-consumption

What is wrong with my code? Any suggestions? 
Thankyou.

My code so far

```
Dim ID(50) As String, Day(50) As Date
Dim Time(50) As Integer, GlobelActivePower(50) As Integer
Dim Sub1(50) As Integer, Sub2(50) As Integer, Sub3(50) As Integer
Public N As Integer

Sub ReadFileSmall()
Dim Infile As String
Infile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Power_smallDataset.csv"
    Open Infile For Input As #1
    N = 0

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Input #1, ID(N), Day(N), Time(N), GlobelActivePower(N), Sub1(N), 
        Sub2(N), Sub3(N)
        N = N + 1
    Loop

Range("A4").Select
For indx = 0 To N - 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(indx, 0).Value = ID(indx)
    ActiveCell.Offset(indx, 1).Value = Day(indx)
    ActiveCell.Offset(indx, 2).Value = Time(indx)
    ActiveCell.Offset(indx, 4).Value = GlobelActivePower(indx)
    ActiveCell.Offset(indx, 5).Value = Sub1(indx)
    ActiveCell.Offset(indx, 6).Value = Sub2(indx)
    ActiveCell.Offset(indx, 7).Value = Sub3(indx)
Next

Close #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The array size is strange.
The following is the data of the csv file.

```
Sub ReadFileSmall()
    Dim Infile As String
    Dim vDB
    Infile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Power_smallDataset.csv"

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Infile, Format:=2
    With ActiveSheet
        vDB = .UsedRange
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (0)

    Range("A4").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), ubouns(vDB, 2)) = vDB
End Sub
```